# Looking for a DNN Search API For Querying

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

My company just purchased the full version of DNN 7.x (Evoq Content) and I am looking for any kind of documentation on a search API I can use for querying content stored within DNN from a remote system and ideally have that API return JSON or XML. Doing Google searches I am unable to find anything but was hopeful there might be a built in API or a plugin which would provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I did not ever find a public open search type of API however what I did find was actually pretty close. I took a look at the source of the search page and found search operations from that page make an AJAX call to a URL that accepts a number of query string parameters which include but are not limited to keywords, tags, document type, sort, etc. Fortunately the response returns a pretty clear to understand JSON response so it was really trivial to wrap a C# helper class which builds/formats the URL to pass into DNN.